# spray-routing with spray-can - Hand off to actor only works sometimes in my application

Tags: scala, spray

Sorry, this is kind of long, because I need to include various files.

**Problem**

I am not sure what is going on in my setup [using spray 1.3.3]. I am trying to do file uploads using chunked requests which seemed to work as expected once or twice, but for some reason most of the time the actor never receives the chunks after the initial registration of the chunk handler is finished. It just disappears into oblivion and my request and logs just keep waiting the whole time. The 2 times out of 50 it did work were when I ran through the debugger. However even with the debugger it doesn't work mostly.

Based on various examples and discussions related to DemoService and FileUploadHandler, I am using spray-can to check the received HttpMessage for chunks, and at that point spawn off a separate route. I use curl with chunked encoding to test my output.

Please help! I have spent too many hours trying to get chunked requests mixed with routes working for my use case.

**Code**

Here is the code I have:

TestApp.scala

```
object TestApp extends App with GlobalConfig {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("TestApp")
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val healthActor = system.actorOf(Props[HealthStateActor])

  val routes = new HealthcheckController(healthActor).route ~
               new ResourceController().route

  val requestRouter = system.actorOf(Props(new HttpRequestCustomHandler(routes)))

  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(requestRouter, "0.0.0.0", HttpBindPort)
}
```

FileUploadActor.scala

```
class FileUploadActor(client: ActorRef, requestMetadata: RequestMetadata, request: HttpRequest, ctx: RequestContext)
  extends Actor with ActorLogging with GlobalConfig {

  import request._

  var bytesWritten = 0L
  var bytes: Array[Byte] = "".getBytes

 // client ! CommandWrapper(SetRequestTimeout(Duration.Inf)) // cancel timeout

  def receive = {
    case c: MessageChunk =>
      log.info(s"Got ${c.data.length} bytes of chunked request $method $uri")

      bytes ++= c.data.toByteArray
      bytesWritten += c.data.length

    case e: ChunkedMessageEnd =>
      log.info(s"Got end of chunked request $method $uri. Writing $bytesWritten bytes for upload: $requestMetadata")

      Try(saveFile(requestMetadata)) match {
        case Success(_) => ctx.complete(HttpResponse(StatusCodes.Created, entity = "success"))
        case Failure(f) => f.printStackTrace(); ctx.complete(HttpResponse(StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "failure"))
      }

  //    client ! CommandWrapper(SetRequestTimeout(UploadRequestTimeout.seconds)) // reset timeout to original value
      context.stop(self)
  }
}
```

FileUploadService.scala

The RegisterChunkHandler message is the last step where I see the debugger stop at break points, and where the logs go quiet. When it does work I can see MessageChunk messages being received by FileUploadActor.

```
trait FileUploadService extends Directives {
  this: Actor with ActorLogging with GlobalConfig =>

  def chunkedRoute() = {

    path(resourceAPI / "upload" / "resource" / Segment) { resourceId =>
      put {
        detach() {

            ctx => {
              val request = ctx.request
              val client = sender()

              val handler = context.actorOf(Props(new FileUploadActor(client,
                RequestMetadata(....),
                request, ctx)))

              sender ! RegisterChunkHandler(handler)
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HttpRequestCustomHandler.scala

```
class HttpRequestCustomHandler(routes: Route, resourceProviderRef: ResourceProvider)
  extends HttpServiceActor
  with FileUploadService
  with ActorLogging
  with GlobalConfig {

  val normal = routes
  val chunked = chunkedRoute()

  def resourceProvider = resourceProviderRef

  val customReceive: Receive = {
    // clients get connected to self (singleton handler)
    case _: Http.Connected => sender ! Http.Register(self)

    case r: HttpRequest =>
      normal(RequestContext(r, sender(), r.uri.path).withDefaultSender(sender()))

    case s@ChunkedRequestStart(HttpRequest(PUT, path, _, _, _)) =>
      chunked(RequestContext(s.request, sender(), s.request.uri.path).withDefaultSender(sender()))
  }

  override def receive: Receive = customReceive
}
```

HttpRequestHandler.scala

```
abstract class HttpRequestHandler(routes: Route) extends HttpServiceActor{

  override def receive: Receive = runRoute(routes)
}
```

application.conf:

```
spray.can.server {
  request-timeout = 20 s

  pipelining-limit = disabled
  reaping-cycle = infinite
  stats-support = off
  request-chunk-aggregation-limit = 0

  parsing.max-content-length = 100000000
  parsing.incoming-auto-chunking-threshold-size = 15000000
  chunkless-streaming = on

  verbose-error-messages = on
  verbose-error-logging = on
}
```

curl **Success:**

```
    curl -vvv -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -d    
'@/Users/abc/Documents/test.json' 
'http://localhost:8180/upload/resource/02521081'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8100 (#0)
> PUT /upload/resource/02521081 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8100
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data
> Content-Length: 82129103
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
* Server spray-can/1.3.3 is not blacklisted
< Server: spray-can/1.3.3
< Date: Mon, 17 Aug 2015 07:45:58 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 7
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
success
```

**Failure with same curl** (waits forever):

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8100 (#0)
> PUT /upload/resource/02521081 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
> Host: localhost:8100
> Accept: */*
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

^C
```

**Failure** (waits forever):

```
resource 2015-08-17 01:33:09.374  [Resource] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger   - Slf4jLogger started
resource 2015-08-17 01:33:09.396 08:33:09.382UTC [Resource] DEBUG akka.event.EventStream main EventStream(akka://resource) - logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
resource 2015-08-17 01:33:09.404 08:33:09.383UTC [Resource] DEBUG akka.event.EventStream main EventStream(akka://resource) - Default Loggers started
resource 2015-08-17 01:33:10.160 08:33:10.159UTC [Resource] INFO  spray.can.server.HttpListener Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 akka://resource/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0 - Bound to /0.0.0.0:8100
```

**Success** (logs edited for clarity):

```
resource 2015-08-17 00:42:12.283  [Resource] INFO  akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger   - Slf4jLogger started
resource 2015-08-17 00:42:12.295 07:42:12.290UTC [Resource] DEBUG akka.event.EventStream main EventStream(akka://resource) - logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
resource 2015-08-17 00:42:12.308 07:42:12.291UTC [Resource] DEBUG akka.event.EventStream main EventStream(akka://resource) - Default Loggers started
resource 2015-08-17 00:42:13.007 07:42:13.005UTC [Resource] INFO  spray.can.server.HttpListener Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4 akka://resource/user/IO-HTTP/listener-0 - Bound to /0.0.0.0:8100
resource 2015-08-17 00:43:47.615 07:43:47.529UTC [Resource] DEBUG c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 akka://resource/user/$b/$b - Got 131072 bytes of chunked request PUT http://localhost:8100/resourcesvc/0.2/api/upload/resource/02521081-20e5-483a-929f-712a9e11d117/content/5adfb5-561d-4577-b6ad-c6f42eef98
resource 2015-08-17 00:43:49.220 07:43:49.204UTC [Resource] DEBUG c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 akka://resource/user/$b/$b - Got 131072 bytes of chunked request PUT http://localhost:8100/resourcesvc/0.2/api/upload/resource/02521081-20e5-483a-929f-712a9e11d117/content/5adfb5-561d-4577-b6ad-c6f42eef98
.
.
.
resource 2015-08-17 00:44:05.605 07:44:05.605UTC [Resource] DEBUG c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 akka://resource/user/$b/$b - Got 45263 bytes of chunked request PUT http://localhost:8100/resourcesvc/0.2/api/upload/resource/02521081-20e5-483a-929f-712a9e11d117/content/5adfb5-561d-4577-b6ad-c6f42eef98
resource 2015-08-17 00:44:05.633 07:44:05.633UTC [Resource] INFO  c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 akka://resource/user/$b/$b - Got end of chunked request PUT http://localhost:8100/resourcesvc/0.2/api/upload/resource/02521081-20e5-483a-929f-712a9e11d117/content/5adfb5-561d-4577-b6ad-c6f42eef98. Writing 82129103 bytes for upload: RequestMetadata(...,multipart/form-data)
resource 2015-08-17 00:44:05.634 07:44:05.633UTC [Resource] DEBUG c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 akka://resource/user/$b/$b - actor is akka://resource/user/$b/$b, sender is Actor[akka://resource/temp/$a], client is Actor[akka://resource/temp/$a]
resource 2015-08-17 00:45:58.445  [Resource] DEBUG com.abc.resource.io.FileClient$   - UploadResult@109a69fb
resource 2015-08-17 00:45:58.445  [Resource] DEBUG com.abc.resource.io.FileClient$   - upload is done: true
```

Please let me know if you see anything weird. What is usually the reason an actor would vanish like this? Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I added further logging and see that the from and to actors are apparently both turning into deadLetters even though that is clearly not the case in the log line above that. This is when message 'RegisterChunkHandler' is sent to sender in FileUploadService.scala.

```
sender ! RegisterChunkHandler(handler)
```

Related log:

```
resource 2015 - 0 8 - 17 21: 14: 32.173 20: 14: 32.173 UTC[Resource] DEBUG c.l.a.io.HttpRequestCustomHandler Resource - akka.actor.default - dispatcher - 3 akka :// Resource / user / httpcustomactor - sender is Actor[akka :// Resource / temp / $a]
resource 2015 - 0 8 - 17 21: 14: 32.175 20: 14: 32.175 UTC[Resource] INFO  akka.actor.DeadLetterActorRef A4Resource-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6 akka://A4Resource/deadLetters - Message [spray.can.Http$RegisterChunkHandler] from Actor[akka://A4Resource/user/httpcustomactor#-1286373908] to Actor[akka://A4Resource/deadLetters] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
resource 2015 - 0 8 - 17 21: 14: 32.176 20: 14: 32.176 UTC[Resource] DEBUG c.l.resource.actor.FileUploadActor Resource - akka.actor.default - dispatcher - 7 akka :// Resource / user / httpcustomactor / $a - pre - start
```

Any idea how this can be avoided?